# Display users email when logged in (JSF 2.0)

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, java-ee-6

My web app has a template that is used in all pages. I want to create a little label in that template (so it's visible everywhere) to display the email of the user if it's currently logged in.

I think the best way is to directly see if it exist on the session, so this is how I created the label:

```
<h:outputLabel id="usernameLabel"
               value="#{FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                      .getSessionMap().get("userRole")}" />
```

The code is not syntactically correct. How can I write it in the appropriate manner to achieve my goal? Do you think this approach is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The better approach would be to store userBean in session containing the user's information.

and then

```
#{userBean.email}
```

Or you can directly attribute from session using jsp el

```
${userRole}
```

I would prefer first approach

**Update**

Upon successful login, set the frequently required in a ManagedBean for example

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class CurrentUserInfo{
  private String userName;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  //and some other like DOB and etc..
  //+accessor methods 
}
```

This would be alive and accessible through the session

Comment: Create a session scoped bean and give it the name 'userBean'. Then add a field `email` as well as a getter and fill the field upon login.

Comment: It works nice sorry i got confused, i dont need a managed bean for that, it is the key stored in the session what i am calling :)
I used the second approach no need for managed bean.